# Visual Studio or boost::asio bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, visual-studio-2015, boost-asio

I've just "upgraded" `MSVC2015` to Update 2 and encountered `boost::asio` [issue 12115](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12115)...

I'm glad to say that the workaround described in `boost issue 12115` i.e. removing `service_has_move` from line 43 of `basic_io_object.hpp` works fine to change:

```
#if defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_MOVE)
...
static const bool value =
  sizeof(service_has_move::eval(
    static_cast<service_type*>(0),
    static_cast<implementation_type*>(0))) == 1;
...
#endif // defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_MOVE)
```

to

```
#if defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_MOVE)
...
static const bool value =
  sizeof(eval(
    static_cast<service_type*>(0),
    static_cast<implementation_type*>(0))) == 1;
...
#endif // defined(BOOST_ASIO_HAS_MOVE)
```

I'm not a great fan of editing libraries, especially not `boost`!
So can someone please tell me whether this is actually a `boost` issue or whether the issue is `MSVC2015` changing it's `move` behaviour in Update 2?

FYI, the original code compiled and worked fine under `MSVC2015` Update 1 and `MinGW` 4.9.2 (on Windows 10) and `GCC` 5.3.1 (on Fedora) using both `boost` `1.60.0` and `1.61.0`.
I'm currently using `boost` `1.61.0` but `boost issue 12115` was raised on  `boost` `1.60.0`.

Comment: What do you mean by "at fault"? Oftentimes that is subjective or ambiguous. It might be better to ask a programming question, or describe some sort of constructive goal.

Comment: Sorry @ChrisBeck I was annoyed that the code no longer compiled after the "upgrade". I've edited the question to address the specific issue of `MSVC2015 Update 2` move behaviour. I've also reported the issue to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty obvious who is at fault. If you had to delete something in boost to fix this, then boost is at fault, no? The macro `BOOST_ASIO_HAS_MOVE` is defined based on compiler detection in the boost config header(s). Obviously when you updated, the compiler version and other info that these headers relies on was not a match, so the namespace you had to delete was not defined.